# I have template function. by using function std::for_each replace every positive number by biggest number from this container

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, type-conversion, value-type

template function gets 2 iterators, begin and end iterators.
template data type `iterType` is iterator type. I have error when trying to equate current iterator value to maximal value in lambda function right here:
`[&](iterType* current) {if (current > 0) current = max; }`

```
    template<typename iterType>
    void modify_each(iterType beg,iterType end) //3.3 #17
    {
        typename iterType::value_type max = *beg;
        for (auto it = beg; it != end; it++)
        {
            if (max < *it)  max = *it;
        }

        std::for_each(beg, end, [&](iterType* current) {if (current > 0) current = max; });
    }
```

Comment: In order to make the support quicker, please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The member `current` is a pointer, therefore it probably always is bigger than zero.
Your lambda must accept iterator object and dereference it within the function. Try the following.

```
[&](iterType &current) {if (*current > 0) *current = max; });
```

Comment: compiler says : "cannot convert argument 1 from `int` to `iterType &`

Comment: OK. In that case, try argument type int like following `[&](int &current)...`

Comment: by the way container is filled with integers so `*current` points to int value

Comment: If you observe it in dereference context - yeah it does, but if you observe it in variable declaration context - it is a pointer.

Comment: If you type `int *a = 5` it is a pointer, but if you type `*a = 10` it is an `int&` (the content of the pointer). Detailed information you can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
template<typename iterType>
void modify_each(iterType beg,iterType end) //3.3 #17
{
    typename iterType::value_type max = *beg;
    for (auto it = beg; it != end; it++)
    {
        if (max < *it)  max = *it;
    }

    std::for_each(beg, end, [=](typename iterType::value_type& current) {if (current > 0) current = max; });
}
```

Comment: Pointers are valid iterator though... [`std::iterator_traits<It>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your lambda take wrong type.

You might do:

```
template<typename It>
void modify_each(It beg, It end) //3.3 #17
{
    if (beg == end) return; // Empty range
    const auto it = std::max_element(beg, end);

    std::for_each(beg, end, [&](auto& current) { if (current > 0) current = *it; });
}
```

if you don't have generic lambda, you might use `decltype(*beg)` instead of `auto&`.
Alternatively, you might use type from [`std::iterator_traits<It>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).